# How to count specific rows?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, aggregate

I have an example of pyspark dataframe:

| X | Y | Z | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 41 | 63 | 2016-01-01 |
| 23 | 41 | 5 | 2016-01-01 |
| 23 | 41 | 75 | 2016-01-01 |
| 23 | 41 | 46 | 2016-12-01 |
| 23 | 41 | 23 | 2016-12-01 |
| 27 | 41 | 5 | 2016-01-01 |
| 27 | 41 | 75 | 2016-01-01 |
| 27 | 41 | 85 | 2016-01-01 |
| 27 | 41 | 71 | 2016-01-01 |

What I want is to count rows with the same `X`, `Y` and `DATE` columns and store the value in a new column.

Final dataframe should looks like this:

| X | Y | Z | DATE | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 41 | 63 | 2016-01-01 | 3 |
| 23 | 41 | 5 | 2016-01-01 | 3 |
| 23 | 41 | 75 | 2016-01-01 | 3 |
| 23 | 41 | 46 | 2016-12-01 | 2 |
| 23 | 41 | 23 | 2016-12-01 | 2 |
| 27 | 41 | 5 | 2016-01-01 | 4 |
| 27 | 41 | 75 | 2016-01-01 | 4 |
| 27 | 41 | 85 | 2016-01-01 | 4 |
| 27 | 41 | 71 | 2016-01-01 | 4 |

Comment: post your minimal coding attempt

Comment: you can achieve this by using the count function over your desired window. [here's](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-window-functions/) a good blog with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help (assuming you mistyped and wanted Count instead of sum):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import count

df = df.withColumn("Count", count("*").over(Window.partitionBy("X", "Y", "Date")))
```